# Retrieving the response body from an HttpClientResponse

Tags: dart

I'm trying to write some tests for my Dart server application, and I've been using the HttpClient class (along with the related HttpClientRequest and HttpClientResponse classes to make test requests to the server (note that I'm using these classes because I need the dart:io package for running the server, so I can't also import dart:html). This has been going fairly well so far, and I've been able to write tests to check that the server is returning responses with the correct HTTP Status code. The base of the code I've been using to make these test calls is as follows:

```dart
Future<HttpClientResponse> makeServerRequest(String method, Uri uri, [String jsonData]) async {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest request = await client.openUrl(method, uri);
  request.write(jsonData);
  return request.close();
}
```

Now I need to write a test that makes sure that the body of the response, not just the status code, is correct. The problem is that I can't seem to find anything that allows me to actually access the response body in the HttpClient* classes. The closest I've been able to find so far is the [HttpClientResponse.contentLength](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.HttpClientResponse#id_contentLength) property, but that only tells me how big the response body is, and isn't the actual content.

How do I retrieve the response body from these requests? Or, if you aren't able to, is there some other way I can make the requests on a server side application so I can read the responses?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `HttpClientResponse` object is a `Stream`, so you can just read it with the `listen()` method:

```dart
response.listen((List<int> data) {
  //data as bytes
});
```

You can also use the codecs from `dart:convert` to parse the data. The following example reads the response contents to a String:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

Future<String> readResponse(HttpClientResponse response) {
  final completer = Completer<String>();
  final contents = StringBuffer();
  response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((data) {
    contents.write(data);
  }, onDone: () => completer.complete(contents.toString()));
  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I was searching so hard for something analogous to [HttpRequest.responseText](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.HttpRequest#id_responseText) that I completely overlooked that the HttpClientResponse is a Stream. Quick secondary question though, is there any reason you're using a StringBuffer and StreamTransformer rather than decoding the result from a BytesBuilder?

Comment: There is no specific reason. I just improved the example available in the docs: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.HttpClientResponse. Maybe you can achieve a better performance with a BytesBuilder

Comment: this is so confusing, I started from this example and also the other ones found in the documentation. I'm stuck with a Future object at best, I can't get it out of the scope into a simple String var. I am able to read the response body within the `.then((String body) => print(body)`. but I can't pass that content outside of that scope. 

```
String _get_response_body(String url) sync* {
  String out;
  http.get(url).then((response) {
    print(" status: ${response.statusCode}");
    print(" body: ${response.body}");
    out = readResponse(response);
  });

  return out;
}

Comment: what package do i import? i imported `dart:convert` but it isn't working

Comment: This is now broken with the latest dart version, not sure which exactly but I ran flutter upgrade and the above code now has these errors: `The argument type 'Utf8Decoder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>'.` for the transform parameter & `The argument type 'Null Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)'.` for the listen parameter.

Comment: I actually just found a solution in this [post](https://github.com/dart-lang/co19/issues/383), casting the stream to a `List<int>` before the transform reverts the breaking change (`.cast<List<int>>()` right before calling `.tranform(...)`).

Comment: I would suggest to add error catching : 


```dart
var completer = Completer();
    var contents = StringBuffer();
    response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen(
      (data) => contents.write(data),
      onDone: () => completer.complete(contents.toString()),
      onError: (e) => completer.completeError(e),
    );
    return completer.future;
```

Comment: For me it is giving error: A value of type 'Future can't be returned from method 'readResponse' because it has a return type of 'Future<String>'.

Comment: How could just reading the body of an Http response be so ugly? Dart is soooo bad.

Comment: @ScottF well this is dart's low-level API for IO operations. They also have a high-level API for HTTP: https://pub.dev/packages/http

Answer (score 9):

### Low level

Here is the `await for` version of collecting the response stream. It's a little more compact than using a completer.

```dart
Future<String> readResponse(HttpClientResponse response) async {
  final contents = StringBuffer();
  await for (var data in response.transform(utf8.decoder)) {
    contents.write(data);
  }
  return contents.toString();
}
```

You should wrap it in a `try catch` block to handle errors.

### High level

Most of the time from the client side you would use the [`http`](https://pub.dev/packages/http) library instead:

```dart
// import 'package:http/http.dart';

Response response = await get(url);
String content = response.body;
```

See [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-http-requests-in-flutter-d12e98ee1cef) for more details.

Comment: Good job, it is working for me. <<await for>> was the key of my problem

Answer (score 2):

A short way of getting the body from an `HttpClientResponse` is:

```
Future<String> readResponse(HttpClientResponse response) async {
  return response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
}
```

Comment: with new Dart it becomes: return utf8.decoder(response.bodyBytes);