# Retrieving String from HttpClientResponse class in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to retrieve response as a string in dart and I am referring to below code:

```
  Future<String> readResponse(HttpClientResponse response) {
    var completer = new Completer();
    var contents = new StringBuffer();
    response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((data) {
      contents.write(data);
    }, onDone: () => completer.complete(contents.toString()));
    return completer.future;
  }
```

I got the reference fro this link : 
[Retrieving the response body from an HttpClientResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808848/retrieving-the-response-body-from-an-httpclientresponse)

but this is giving me an error:

> A value of type 'Future can't be returned from method 'readResponse'
>   because it has a return type of 'Future'.

I am learning dart and I am not able to figure out the solution for it, I am using Dart 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the type for `Completer`.

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<String> readResponse(HttpClientResponse response) {
  var completer = Completer<String>();
  var contents = StringBuffer();
  response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((data) {
    contents.write(data);
  }, onDone: () => completer.complete(contents.toString()));
  return completer.future;
}
```