# Cannot build up a string using StringBuffer and a server response

Tags: dart

I'm trying to fetch data from [this link](https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty) via Dart. Since I'm making use of `dart:io` library's `HttpClientResponse` based instance to **listen** to the data obtained from the above link, therefore I thought that an instance of `StringBuffer` would be the best option to capture the received data. It would help me to build the response string in an incremental fashion. But it seems like I'm not making proper use of `StringBuffer`, because in the end the response string (stored in `receivedBuffer`) remains empty.

Code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async
{
  StringBuffer receivedBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
  String url = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty";

  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

  print("[info] Fetch successful. Proceeding to transform received data ...");
  response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) => receivedBuffer.write(contents));

  print("[info] Done. Contents:\n");
  print(receivedBuffer);
}
```

Output :

```
[info] Fetch successful. Proceeding to transform received data ...
[info] Done. Contents:
```

Also, instead of `receivedBuffer.write(contents)`, if I were to write `print(contents)`, then all the
required data is printed as one would expect it to. But while trying to write the `contents` to `recievedBuffer` it seems like `receivedBuffer` wasn't even updated once.
I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808848/retrieving-the-response-body-from-an-httpclientresponse), and tried to incorporate the answer present over there in my code. To be precise, I made use of `Completer` instance to take care of my issue, but it didn't help.

What's the issue in the above provided code?

Comment: Try to print the buffer inside the `onDone` function which you can set in the `listen()` funtion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for the stream to complete.

In the `listen` call, you set up a receiver for stream events, but you don't wait for the events to arrive.
You can either add an `onDone` parameter to the `listen` call and do something there, but more likely you will want to just wait for it here, and then I recommend:

```dart
  await response.transform(utf8.decoder).forEach(receivedBuffer.write);
```

Using `forEach` is usually what you want when you are calling `listen`, but not remembering the returned subscription. Alternatively use an `await for`:

```dart
  await for (var content in response.transform(utf8.decoder)) {
    receivedBuffer.write(content);
  }
```

(which corresponds to a `forEach` call in most ways).

Comment: 2 more questions: (1) If I were to use directly use `await response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((content) => receivedBuffer.write(content))` instead, then would it lead to some other issue? Because I used this statement and the effect of this statement was as same as the statements suggested by you. (2) Does Dart prefer to execute statements that lie beyond a stream listen type of statements prior to completion of the stream? I believe this to be true, because it helps me explain the result that my code generated after I incorporated the change suggested by @Mattia.

Comment: 1) You can't await the result of calling `listen`. It returns a stream subscription, not a future. Waiting for that does nothing except insert a minuscule delay, and it does not wait for the stream to complete. The `forEach` call does return a future which completes when the stream is done. So yes, same issues.

Comment: 2)  When you call `listen`, it immediately returns a stream subscription and then starts to wait for asynchronous events on the stream. The code after the `call` to listen will continue running immediately. Then later, potentially much later, events will appear on the stream and call the event handlers you have attached to the subscription. When the stream ends, if it does, the `onDone` handler is called. What happens in those callbacks is entirely up to you, so if you need other code to wait for the stream end, you need to tell them about it in your `onDone` handler.

Comment: In regards to the above comment, let's assume that a **listen** statement has been placed in some function `foo()` which has been already executed (all implies every statement apart from the **listen** one) and currently some other function `bar()` is under execution. While `bar()` is getting executed, the above mentioned **listen** statement receives it last value, then will Dart jump back to that **listen** statement's `onDone` argument directly or will it wait for the end of execution of `bar()`?

Comment: Assume that the stream is closed by someone calling `StreamController.close`. That schedules a microtask to call the `onDone` handler. Then nothing further will happen until control returns to the microtask queue. That means that `bar` will have to return, as will the code that called `bar`, until the function that was last called by the microtask queue returns. Then the microtask can continue to the next scheduled task (or if there are none, the event loop can continue to the next event). At some point, the scheduled microtask will run to call the `onDone` handler.

Comment: Thankyou. Can you point me to the source of these info., so that I can make use of them for an elaborate read?

Comment: The primary resource on futures would be https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await and https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-async/Future-class.html. The event loop is described in http://dartdoc.takyam.com/articles/event-loop/. I hope this will be enough to get you started.